# Как передать значение между страницами?

Tags: javascript

На одной странице я создал форму для ввода имени, *e-mail* и собственно текста сообщения. После нажатия на этой же странице кнопки "Отправить сообщение", открывается новая страница, в которой содержатся данные полей, заполненных в предыдущей.

Как это сделать?

Нашел в Интернете разные скрипты, но некоторые используют *php*. Я работал и с *PHP*, но когда я указываю полный путь, кнопка не хочет работать:

```
<form method="post" action="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\UserMail.php"> 
<input type="submit">
```

Переделал один скрипт, получилась такая вот штука:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function goMail(){ 
    var UsName=document.getElementsByName(('UserName').value); 
    if (confirm("Уверены, что хотите отправить сообщение?")) { 
    document.location="UserMail.html?id="+UsName; } 
    }
</script>

<form>
<p>Ваше имя: </p>
<input type="text" name="userName" value="">
<br>
<input type ="button" value="Отправить сообщение" onClick="goMail()">
<form>
```

Страница новая открывается, но вот ничего не передается... Чисто там...
Вот код той страницы:

```
<td valign="top" colspan="4" align="center">
<font id="UsName">
</font>
</td>
```

Что нужно и как сделать?

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то попробуйте использовать кукки)

Comment: cookie не всегда подходит т.к. имеет ограничение на длину.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно заполнить поля данными, переданными в строке запроса (у тебя только `id`).
Если использовать только `javascript`, то у `<body>` новой страницы нужно добавить событие `onload`, в котором после загрузки страницы прочтешь переданные значения параметров  и вставишь их в нужные поля.
Для чтения параметров можно использовать функцию отсюда http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html

Пишу ответ здесь, чтобы код был виден кодом.
Первая страница:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function goMail() {
        if (confirm("Уверены, что хотите отправить сообщение?")) {
            document.location = "UserMail.html?id=" + document.getElementById("userName").value;
        }
    }
</script>
<form>
    <p>Ваше имя: </p>
    <input id="userName" type="text" name="userName" value="" />
    <br/>
    <input type ="button" value="Отправить сообщение" onclick="goMail()" />
</form>
```

Вторая (для учебных целей и с одним параметром можно обойтись и без доп. функции):

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function OnLoad() {
            var paramValue = window.location.href.split("?")[1].split("=")[1];
            document.getElementById("UsName").innerHTML = paramValue;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="OnLoad()">
    <font id="UsName">
    </font>
</body>
```

Comment: Извините Georgy!) А как будет выглядеть это всё для моего варианта?) Я рассмотрел вашу функцию на  http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html, но, извините конечно, я в JavaScript совсем недавно, около недели, да и вообще в WEB-программирование чайник, так что я много не понял... Можете пояснить на моем примере? Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо огромное Georgy!) Все хорошо работает для одного параметра. Но допустим надо передать не только Имя, но и e-mail причем чтобы их можно было расположить в разных ячейках. Как это реализовать? Я пробовал менять вашу функцию, но в итоге передает один E-mail...
Вот ввод:
<p>Ваш e-mail:</p>
<input id="userMail" type="text" name="userMail" value="">

В goMail() добавил
var UsMail = document.getElementsByName(('userMail').value);
if (confirm("Уверены, что хотите отправить сообщение?")) {
...
document.location = "UserMail.html?id=" + document.getElementById "userMail").value;}
Как быть дальше

Answer (score 2):

Для нескольких параметров:

```
function OnLoad() {
            var query = window.location.href.split("?")[1]; // результат - строка запроса без адреса страницы "id=someName&userMail=some@mail.com&usText=MemoText"
            var params = query.split("&");  // результат - массив строк из пар "id=someName", "userMail=some@mail.com", "usText=MemoText"
            // теперь брать по очереди
            document.getElementById("UsName").innerHTML = params[0].split("=")[1];
            document.getElementById("userMail").innerHTML = params[1].split("=")[1];
            document.getElementById("usText").innerHTML = params[2].split("=")[1];
   }
```

К последнему параметру надо добавить:

```
params[2].split("=")[1].split("#")[0];
```

Иначе, если в ссылке будет якорь, он войдет в значение.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, для нескольких параметров:

```
    function OnLoad() {
            var query = window.location.href.split("?")[1]; // результат - строка запроса без адреса страницы "id=someName&userMail=some@mail.com&usText=MemoText"
            var params = query.split("&");  // результат - массив строк из пар "id=someName", "userMail=some@mail.com", "usText=MemoText"
            // теперь брать по очереди
            document.getElementById("UsName").innerHTML = params[0].split("=")[1];
            document.getElementById("userMail").innerHTML = params[1].split("=")[1];
            document.getElementById("usText").innerHTML = params[2].split("=")[1];
   }
```

Если использовать функцию из ссылки, то

```
    function OnLoad() {
            document.getElementById("UsName").innerHTML = gup("id");
            document.getElementById("userMail").innerHTML = gup("userMail");
            document.getElementById("usText").innerHTML = gup("usText");
    }
```

Comment: Извините Georgy!) Снова я!) Что в функции gomail() должно быть?)
Я написал так)
function goMail() {
  var UsName = document.getElementsByName(('userName').value);
  var UsMail = document.getElementsByName(('userMail').value);
  var UsText = document.getElementsByName(('userText').value);
   if (confirm("Уверены...")){
   document.location = "UserMail.html?id="+ document.getElementById"userName").value + 
document.getElementById("userMail").value + 
document.getElementById("userText").value;}}
Пробовал для каждого обозначить document.location, но в итоге передает только последнее значение...

Comment: Лучше не угадывать, а почитать. document.location открывает новую страницу, у нас UserMail.html, дальше '?' и список параметров, в виде [имя параметра]=[значение], разделяются параметры с помощью '&', т.е. в итоге  document.location должно быть присвоено что-то вроде UserMail.html?id=someName&userMail=some@mail.com&usText=MemoText.

Comment: Функция выглядет так:

function goMail() {
            if (confirm("Уверены...")) {
                var UsName = document.getElementsByName('userName').value;
                var UsMail = document.getElementsByName('userMail').value;
                var UsText = document.getElementsByName('userText').value;
                document.location = "UserMail.html?id=" + UsName + '&userMail=' + UsMail + '&usText=' + UsText;
            }
        }

Comment: Что посоветуете почитать, Georgy?) За разъяснение document.location огромное спасибо, все оч понятно, мне бы такого лектора по web-программированию;) Сделал как вы написали, но почему то передает значение "undefined"... Значит либо не читает содержимое, либо не может найти нужные элементы?... В чем беда то?(

Comment: Возможно синтаксис. Надо писать не document.getElementsByName(('XXXXX').value), а document.getElementsByName('XXXXX').value

Для "почитать" :) - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_examples.asp

Comment: Ммм нет.. Написано все как вы и указали... Дело наверное не в этом...

Comment: вышли мне на мыло, посмотрю

Comment: Ок, мыло пожалуйста дайте;)

Comment: У меня в профиле, если не видно giababu2000@yahoo.com

Answer (score 1):

Ok, посмотрел.
Во-первых, не `getElementsByName`, а `getElementById` (в последние разы сам у тебя скопировал ..`ByName`, а не ..`ById`, сорри), во-вторых, у тебя `textarea` c `name=userText` не имеет `id`. 
Потом, атрибуты `name=..` не нужно указывать, если нигде не используешь, нужно указывать `id=..`

Т.е.

1.

```
function goMail() {
            if (confirm("Уверены...")) {
                var UsName = document.getElementById('userName').value;
                var UsMail = document.getElementById('userMail').value;
                var UsText = document.getElementById('userText').value;
                document.location = "UserMail.html?id=" + UsName + '&userMail=' + UsMail + '&usText=' + UsText;
            }
        }
```

2.

```
<textarea id = "userText" ...
```

Comment: Ооо огромное спасибо, Georgy!) Вот ссылочка по архив, с сайтом, все я думаю готово!) Если что можете посоветовать или подсказать, то буду оч благодарен)
http://letitbit.net/download/60498.6a836550baae932aa09d808268ef/divanchik.rar.html

Answer (score 1):

а зачем внедрять js, если он совершенно для этого не нужен? Форма передаст заполненные данные, забирайте их из массива и присваивайте новой форме, слоям или еще чему угодно :)Если только ради "уверены что хотите отправить", то можно просто чекбокс поставить, который делает активной кнопку отправки...

для php - полный путь указывать не надо, такой оно не осилит :) используйте относительные пути.

Comment: Ama, если бы вы прочли коментарии выше, то поняли что я "в WEB-программирование чайник";) Если приведете пример вашего ответа, то я буду Вам оч благодарен:)